# Semi automatic way to change data structure on excel or others tools?

Tags: excel

Any idea how to convert this structured data:

[image]

into the following?

[image]

I have 30K rows so I would need a semi automatic way to do it if possible.

Thanks for your time

UPDATE:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Excel for Mac 16.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my below screenshot I have used below formula to `B6` cell to extract unique numbers.

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,B2:H4)&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

Then in `B7` cell use `SUMPRODUCT()` to find per client number is exist or not and copy down & across the formula as needed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4=$A7)*($B$2:$H$4=B$6))
```

[image]

Comment: This would be much more intersting if you could offer a formula that Spills the counts.  Perhaps something based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299104)

Comment: I tried the formular but I'm getting a Name error on B6. I attached the screenshots on my original question as I don't know how to add images or files here.

Comment: removing the first formula (B6) it works for me. I can do that one manually. Thanks!! :)